# How to pass addEventListener event value to another function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events, addeventlistener

I created a `addEventListener` and want to send the event to another function so it handles it, but I keep getting this error (on Firefox browser):

> event is not defined!

My `Main.EventHandler` function never runs so I process the event accordingly! Could any one tell me how to fix it?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

var UserAgent  ="Browser";


var Main = {};


function MyFunction()
{

if (UserAgent == "Browser") {
alert("inside if statment ");
  try {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
      KeyCode = event.keyCode;
       alert("value of keyCode is:"+KeyCode);
      if (typeof Main.EventHandler != "undefined"){
       alert("value of keyCode is not undefined"+KeyCode);
        Main.EventHandler(event);
      }
    });
  }
  catch (err) {
    alert("error:"+err);
  }

};//end of if

}; //end ofMyFunction

var KeyCode;
Main.EventHandler = function () {
alert("inside Main.EventHandler function and value of event.keyCode is:"+event.keyCode);
  if (typeof event.keyCode != "undefined") {
    KeyCode = event.keyCode;
  }

};//end of EventHandler


</script>

</head>
<body onload="MyFunction();">

This is test page

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try `Main.EventHandler = function (event) {`

Comment: Thanks for reply May i know why some websites online doesn't put the event variable inside = function() and still it works ?

Comment: It depends on various scenarios. One is how the callback function is triggered, such as [in this example](https://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/agb05wug/)